# Como usar o driver remoto em computador protegido por proxy por meio do software R pacote RSelenium?

Tags: r, web-scraping, proxy, autenticação-http, rvest

Bom, preciso acessar um site na minha rede de trabalho, porém esta é protegida por proxy.

Alguns sites aceitam usar os pacotes httr e rvest, outros não. Para fazer login em site por exemplos não consigo. Exemplo:

```
pro    <- use_proxy("minha.proxy", porta, "meuusuario", "minhasenha")
my_session <- html_session(url, pro)
```

Eu geralmente utilizo esta função de proxy para acessar a url que quero e passar pelo proxy.

Mas em determinados sites, no caso para logar, esta função não roda, ou melhor não consigo logar.

A alternativa que encontrei foi utilizar um driver remoto usando a função `rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"))`, por exemplo. No meu pc pessoal consigo desenrolar todo o código por meio do driver remoto do Pacote RSelenium.
Agora na rede do trabalho não consigo.
As melhores opções que encontrei pesquisando foram:

1)

```
cprof <- list(chromeOptions = list(
args = c('--proxy-server=http://minha.proxy:porta',
         '--proxy-auth=usuario:senha')))
driver<- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), extraCapabilities = cprof)
```

2)

```
cprof <- list(chromeOptions = list(
args = c('--proxy-server=http://ip:porta',
         '--proxy-auth=usuario:senha')))
driver<- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), extraCapabilities = cprof)
```

Isso pra passar na proxy, mas retorna em todos:

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

Esse erro é o que acontece geralmente quando não passa na proxy (eu acho!).

Então, tem alguma forma de passar pelo proxy e abrir o meu driver remoto?
Bom, se tiverem algo a contribuir ficarei grato!

Comment: já tentou fazer com outro browser?

Comment: Sim Daniel, `firefox` e `phantomjs` também. Mas tem o mesmo erro.

Comment: Já tentou algom assim: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29663818/3297472

Comment: Esse tipo de coisa é mto difícil de debugar. Eu não tenho nenhum servidor de proxy para testar!

Comment: Tentei também, o problema é que a função `phantom` parece não funcionar mais `Error: phantom is now defunct. Users can drive PhantomJS via selenium using 
    the RSelenium::rsDriver function or directly using wdman::phantomjs`. Tentei fazer a mudança para o wdman::phantomjs, mas não tive sucesso, por não entender completamente isto.

Comment: Concordo que é bem difícil, penso que cada servidor de proxy tem suas particularidades o que torna mais difícil ainda.

Comment: Tenta usar a node library `puppeteer.js` com o `R`, talvez você consiga com este API. Escrevi algo como começar a usar o `puppeteer.js` [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53339598/scraping-javascript-rendered-webpage-that-references-external-javascript-scripts/53343238#53343238). API do `puppeteer.js` [aqui](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.11.0/docs/api.md).

Comment: Obrigado @JdeMello. Com este método consegui, mas antes de executá-lo tive que fazer uma alteração nas variáveis ambientes. Será prudente colocar a solução que encontrei como resposta a minha pergunta?

Comment: Sim faça, acho uma pergunta pertinente. Obrigado

Comment: Você pode usar docker no servidor do trabalho?  pois creio que a versão conteinerizada do Selenium resolveria o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei UMA solução para meu problema!

Como estou em uma rede institucional, preciso de uma proxy para navegar na internet.
Para que o RStudio utilize a proxy é preciso defini-la dentro do IDE (na função que for usar, como na pergunta) ou mesmo alterar as variáveis ambiente como em:[Referência 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44328512/10749690)).

Foi o que fiz, inseri as variáveis ambiente [referência 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40044773/10749690):

```
variable name: http_proxy
variable value: https://user_id:password@your_proxy:your_port/

variable name: https_proxy
variable value: https:// user_id:password@your_proxy:your_port
```

Esta foi a primeira etapa. Em seguida segui os passos ditos pelo @JdeMello em [Referência 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343238/10749690).
Na Referência 3 basicamente o que fiz foi baixar e instalar o `node.js` [baixar node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), depois instalei o `puppeteer.js`, criei em um bloco de notas e nomeei o arquivo como `scrape_mustard.js` (Ver conteúdo do arquivo em Referência 3) e rodei o `scrape_mustard.js` pelo `node` "criar a página" com a função `system()` no RStudio.

Segue script:

```
setwd("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs") ### 
#OBS.: Tive que mudar o diretório para a pasta no disco C onde o nodejs foi instalado.

## system("npm i puppeteer") ## Esta função fez instalar o Puppteer

library(magrittr)
system("node scrape_mustard.js") ## Rodar o scape_mustard.js e criar a página que preciso

library(httr)
html <- xml2::read_html("~/PAGINA/page.html") ## ler html

html %>% 
rvest::html_nodes("h1") ## capturar o que existe na tag h1
```

Dificuldades:

- Como instalei o node no disco C o diretório teve que ser mudado no Rstudio para lá;
- O scraper_mustard.js (o nome pode ser alterado) também tive que mover para a pasta do nodejs no disco C;
- A definição da página deve ser feita dentro do scraper_mustard.js, ou seja, editar toda vez o arquivo antes de rodá-lo (fiz por `writeLines()`), o porém é que se ele estiver na pasta do nodejs (como fiz) no disco C, necessitará de permissão de administrador.

NOTA:
*Ainda não trabalhei em submeter a página para login, mas já consegui pegar a página que queria, o que antes não era possível.*
*Talvez eu tenha feito os passos encontrados nas referências de maneira equivocada, mas o primeiro passo foi dado, achei justo compartilhar*

Alternativamente irei tentar usar o Docker citado por @José, ainda estou estudando isto.
Espero ter sido claro! Obrigado pessoal!